# Можно ли сделать чат с помощью flask_socketio и telebot?

Tags: flask, telebot, chat

Нужно реализовать тех. поддержку на сайте с помощью Flask_socketio и телеграм бота. Юзер пишет вопрос в чат, и он отправляется в бота где менеджер может ответить юзеру из телеграмма. Есть ли готовые решения на основе данных систем или хотя-бы идеи реализации?